# Is it possible to publish azure functions as precompiled dll's in the azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-runtime

I am developing Azure functions locally on VS and wish to publish them to azure portal later on. I want my function code to be non editable and non visible in the portal.

Is it possible to pre-compile these function to dll's while publishing? I am thinking this also saves the cold time as the function will be pre-compiled. Or do I need at least one function there in which I can add reference to the dll of other functions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you are using Visual Studio 2017 or Visual Studio Code with CLI, that's the default way to publish .NET Azure Functions.

See

- [Publishing a .NET class library as a Function App](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2017/03/16/publishing-a-net-class-library-as-a-function-app/)
- [Visual Studio 2017 Tools for Azure Functions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/05/10/azure-function-tools-for-visual-studio-2017/)
- [Deploy to Azure using Azure Functions](https://code.visualstudio.com/tutorials/functions-extension/getting-started)